# Specific Strings And NSScanner

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string, nsstring

I need to determine whether a string (`sourceString`) contains another string (`queryString`) and if it does, at what offset.

I'm guessing that NSScanner might do the trick but I don't fully understand the documentation.

Let's say `sourceString = @"What's the weather in London today?"`

If I set `queryString` to equal `@"What's the weather"`, I'd like a method that would determine that, in this case, `YES` (`sourceString` does contain `queryString`) and the offset is 0 (i.e. at the start of `sourceString`).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an `NSScanner` for that.  Just use `NSString`'s `-rangeOfString:` method.  Something like:

```
NSString *sourceString = @"What's the weather in London today?";
NSString *queryString = @"What's the weather";
NSRange  range;

range = [sourceString rangeOfString:queryString];
```

After the last call, range will be `{NSNotFound, 0}` if `queryString` is not found.  In this case, you'd get `{0, 18}`, though.

Check out the [documentation](http://17.254.2.129/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:).

Comment: Looks like I was trying to make things needlessly complicated. Many thanks for such an elegant solution.